# Runtime environment variable in Next.js generateMetadata

Tags: next.js, environment-variables

I'm using Next.js and trying to set an environment variable at runtime to change some metadata. From the [description in the Next.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#runtime-environment-variables) docs, I expected this to work. Setting the variable at build time works fine, but it cannot be overwritten at runtime.

This would for example be really helpful so I only need to build a single image for staging and production environments.

I created a minimal reproducible example using `npx create-next-app` and changing the `app/layout.tsx` to use an environment variable for the title:

```tsx
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });
export async function generateMetadata(): Promise<Metadata | undefined> {
  return {
    title: process.env.META_TITLE,
    description: "Generated by create next app",
  }
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Here's the `.env`:

```
META_TITLE="My App"
```

Now building and running the app works fine:

```console
npm run build
```

But I cannot change the `META_TITLE` at runtime:

```console
export META_TITLE="My App (Staging)"
npm run start
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was really simple. Just using `noStore` works inside the `generateMetadata` function. Here's the working example:

```tsx
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { unstable_noStore as noStore } from 'next/cache'
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });
export async function generateMetadata(): Promise<Metadata | undefined> {
  noStore()
  return {
    title: process.env.META_TITLE,
    description: "Generated by create next app",
  }
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}
```